# Adding items to a dictionary from a list

Tags: python-2.7

please how can I add new values to the pos dictionary using the items in j as key and those in z as values

```
j = [3,5]
z = [(560,848), (833,934)]
pos = {2:(545,577), 4:(465,799)}
```

I tried

```
for i in z:
    pos[j] = z[i]
```

but it gives this error: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use zip to create pairs that you can then convert into a dict.  E.g.

```
pos = dict(zip(j, z))
```

If you want it more explicit that would be

```
pos = {}
for key, value in zip(j,z) :
    pos[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to iterate over `j` as well.

[`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) is useful for iterating over two (or more) lists:

```
for jj, zz in zip(j, z):
  pos[jj] = zz
```